# grails: reusable authentication interceptor

Tags: authentication, grails

I found an example of simple grails auth where a beforeInterceptor is used in a controller to redirect users out if they are not logged in. it looks like this:

```
  def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&checkUser,except:['login']]
  def checkUser() {
    if(!session.user) {
      redirect(controller:'home')
      return false
    }
  }
```

This is all well and good if you only have one controller that you must secure. what happens when you have more then one? I cant put the `checkUser` method into a service because a service cannot redirect, and probably doesnt have the `session` object. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you would want to use a grails filters, http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html

but I would strongly suggest you look into [Grails Spring Security](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) instead

Comment: Thanks. i am trying to keep login extremely simple, but that spring security plugin looks very enticing :)

Comment: A lot has changed since 2010... "In versions of Grails prior to Grails 3.0, Grails supported the notion of filters. These are still supported for backwards compatibility but are considered deprecated.  The new interceptors concept in Grails 3.0 is superior..."  https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#interceptors

Answer (score 2):

Grails [Filters](http://www.grails.org/Filters) ought to do the trick. The linked page has an example of using a filter for authentication.